# Calling Native Dll with Java Applet using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, java, dll, applet

Java Class with native Dll's.
i signed Java's export class.

```
public class CardApplet extends Applet implements ActionListener {
public native String reader();

static {
    System.load("C:\\Windows\\system\\CardDriver.dll");
}

public static String Reader() {
    CardApplet cardDrive = new CardApplet();
    String data = "";
    try {
        data = cardDrive.reader();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        data = "-1";
    }
    return data;
}
```

}

Javascipt code:

```
    runApplet = document.getElementById("applet");
    runApplet = document.createElement('applet');
    runApplet.code    = 'CardApplet.class';
    runApplet.archive = 'sCardApplet.jar';
    runApplet.width   = '100px';
    runApplet.height  = '100px';

    var appDiv = document.getElementById('applet_div');
    appDiv.appendChild(runApplet);
```

I later call in `runApplet.Reader();` in Javascript.

The first time I call the applet and Dlls, it works well.  But when I called that applet the fourth or fifth time, it doesn't respond.  I tried Java 6, Java 7 and Java 8, but nothing changed.  Could this be a memory issue?  How do I fix this?

Comment: 1. Does it crash when you test CardApplet with junit or main?  2. Does it carsh when you invoke CardDriver.dll in a c/c++ exe?